# Torque sensitivity of a VFD induction motor through a gearbox?

Tags: control-engineering, motors, torque

I have an application that requires torque limiting and I need to determine if VFD torque limiting will provide sufficient protection. I have used VFDs for torque limiting through gearboxes before with success, but I am hoping to find a way to calculate the result as opposed to just gut feeling.

10HP motor
1775 rpm 
69.5:1 gearbox reduction (im assuming 50% efficient)
25.5 rpm at driving sprocket

I have looked at some frequency drives to get an indication of their torque/amp sensitivity. Ive seen 0.1A, 0.01A, 0.1% of torque and 0.01% of torque as control resolutions, but have not found any literature specifically addressing if this resolution can be reasonably expected.

In this situation I am gearing down, so inertia, backlash and controller reaction time will not be an issue.

Comment: If you are driving a sprocket at 10 hp, the motor needs to supply 20 hp if the gear is 50% efficient.

Comment: @CharlesCowie Good catch, I will fix my numbers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Induction motors don't have a consistent current vs. torque relationship. In order accurately control or limit torque, VFDs must determine an equivalent circuit for the motor then monitor and control the electrical parameters that determine the torque. I believe that VFDs that have a good torque limiting capability will have a specification stating the accuracy with which they can do that. They will only be able to state what can be done at the motor shaft. The variations in torque lost in the gearbox will significantly degrade the torque limiting or controlling accuracy. I suspect that finding out what to expect from the gearbox will be the most important and most difficult task in this situation.

Can you state what VFD models you have experience with and/or are considering for use in this situation?

Re link in comment.

If you click the "Specifications" tab, you will see "PowerFlex 700 AC Drive Technical Data," a document that you should download. On page 4 of that document, you will find:

[image]

You might find another manufacturer that can do better, but I doubt any will do a lot better. When a speed-controlled drive goes into torque limit, the motor will slow down until it reaches an operating point where the limiting value of torque is sufficient to drive the load. If no such point is reached, the drive will be at a standstill. At that point, the torque should not exceed the setpoint, but it may be less than the setpoint.

**Re Answer Posted by Asker**

I went through your answer, made a diagram and added some notes as shown below. The way I interpreted your numbers, my calculations gave slightly different results, but I put yours on the diagram. If you you used "best estimate" losses, I would suggest that you also do the calculations using the highest and lowest losses that you think might be possible. I believe that the lowest losses will show the smallest margin between normal operating torque and the failure level torque.

It seems to me that you might get better performance by sizing the drive for the maximum desired operating torque. You calculations seem to indicate it is sized at the failure level torque.

[image]

Comment: Considering: http://ab.rockwellautomation.com/Drives/PowerFlex-700

Comment: Thanks for your help Charles. I awarded you the bounty, but i think i may go ahead an answer my own question to see if i can get some feedback on my solution.

Comment: Thanks for the bounty. If you post a comment after you post your answer, I believe I will get a notice that will remind me to come back read it.

Comment: My solution is posted, let me know your thoughts.

Comment: I couldn't see your answer while typing mine. I now see you used worst case gearbox efficiency. I would also suggest doing the calculations with best case efficiency.

Comment: Please explain "Startup torque will be ignored by the drive."

Comment: Re: "Some gearbox data and empirical motor current data would go a long way to predicting the performance." It is difficult to estimate operating torque from motor current for utility powered motor. It is extremely difficult for a VFD powered motor. It is better to use measured power for utility powered motors and, for VFD powered motors, VFD operating parameters (torque, percent load or DC bus current).

Comment: AB VFD parameter 024 is an internal torque command read-only display that is active only when the 053 Motor Cntl Sel is set to 4 FVC Vector. That is the higher performance encoderless vector control mode that requires the self tuning procedure to be performed with the motor. That control mode is also required to enable 436 Pos Torque Limit, the torque limit setting that is required for this application.

Comment: Re "No closed loop torque sensor will be used as they are prohibitively expensive." That is no surprise. However, to get the 2% regulation requires only a motor shaft encoder. That is much less expensive, but a substantial addition to the motor cost plus the cost of a special cable in a separate conduit from the motor. The encoder allows torque calculation using motor slip calculated from frequency and speed and/or torque angle calculated from rotor position and the vector value of motor current.

Comment: Disclaimer and context: I am retired and have never been employed by AB or an AB distributer. I don't have experience with the AB Powerflex 700, but I have experience with numerous AFD brands and models, mostly by reading sales and technical literature and by evaluating samples of various brands and models for competitive purposes. I have written sales and technical literature for several brands and models. I have worked with some of those in a dynamometer lab and in numerous factory installations.

Comment: The motor is currently line tied with no VFD. Amping it and compairing it to the base load and max load would give me a better estimate of current torque than my blind guess of 500ft lbs.
VFD drives are a mess of parameters, sure wish they would standardize. Thanks for reviewing that.
A hollow shaft encoder might be a good option if the installation has issues and needs more resolution.
I will recommend the VFD be implemented and post back if it gets installed. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Lots of assumptions. Some gearbox data and empirical motor current data would go a long way to predicting the performance.

Sensorless vector mode  
         Startup torque will be ignored by the drive 
10        hp Powerflex 700 VFD    
10        hp motor    
1775          rpm 
29.6          ft lbs  
69.5          gear box ratio  
200       ft lbs assumed constant gearbox torque consumption, referenced on output    
50%       worst case planetary gearbox efficency (in additon to constant) 
26        rpm @ driving sprocket  
928       ft lbs @ driving sprocket   
95%       estimated chain efficency   
19        rpm @ driven sproket    
1176          ft lbs @ driven sprocket    
             
         Full 10 hp has previously damaged mixing rotor  
1176          ft lbs Estimated emperical damaging torque  
700       ft lbs, desired torque limit    
553       ft lbs, pre gearbox, desired torque limit   
18.8          ft lbs seen by motor, desired torque limit  
500       ft lbs Estimated Normal opperational torque, (motor needs amp'd for emperical data here)    
395       ft lbs, operational torque  
14.2          ft lbs seen by motor, operational torque    
             
15.4%         Torque as range of total

0.1% percent of motor rated toque, torque resolution. It is not clear if this requires torque feedback or not.
 [Page 22 of powerflex700 programming manual](http://literature.rockwellautomation.com/idc/groups/literature/documents/um/20b-um002_-en-p.pdf)    
No closed loop torque sensor will be used as they are prohibitively expensive   
    
Worst published torque regulation on the drive is +/-5% in the [powerflex700 technical data](http://literature.rockwellautomation.com/idc/groups/literature/documents/td/20b-td001_-en-p.pdf) 
    
15.4% > 5%, VFD torque limiting will be satisfactory in this application